# Android animations: xml vs. code

Tags: android, android-animation

In Android we can use xml-based approach to build an animation or we can build one in code.

My question: What approach is prevailing? I understand that this is a pretty vague question, but maybe we could achieve some benefits using one method (for example, xml-based) in some situations when pure programmatic approach is to complicated. Or should I try to build all animations pragmatically.

Comment: IMHO It's always good to separate the logic from the view and animation is part of the 'visibility' things, so I like to keep my animations  in xml forms. Of course there are some ways when you have to make it from code. Like when you have to calculate animation offset dynamically for example.

Answer (score 2):

It's entirely up to you on this one.  If you have any parameters in the animation that need to be determined programmatically, such as speed, length of time or what not, then programmatically is the way to go, but having it set in XML is just fine as well.